# Кодировка phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

После отправки с формы текта на русском языке, в базу текст записывается вот так: ÐšÑ€ÑƒÑ‚Ð¾ Как можно исправить это? Какая кодировка должна стоять в скрипте и в бд?

Comment: в бд утф-8 =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_query ("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $db);
```

Вот так поставь будет работать.

Comment: под $db подразумевается переменная хранящая mysql_connect()

Comment: Теперь в базу заносит вопросики и их же выводит! Я применяю это в исполняющем скрипте и на страничке где это должно вывестись)

Comment: в начале гдt пишешь mysql_connect

Answer (score 0):

> Какая кодировка должна стоять в скрипте и в бд?

Одинаковая, к примеру в скрипте windows-1251 -> в бд cp-1251-general-ci

Comment: А кодировка соединения на что влияет? :-)

Comment: Тут с практической точки зрения проще, ненужны лишнии ф-ции конверта кодировок если данные из скрипта и база в одной кодировке.

Answer (score 0):

Если PHP 5 || >, а MySQL 5.0.7 || > то лучше использовать функцию:

```
 mysql_set_charset();
```

Если нет, то после подключения к БД делать запрос:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: Это непомогает!
При регистрации, в базу заносятся ÐšÑ€ÑƒÑ‚Ð¾ а выводятся нормальные русские буквы. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Сам скрипт сохранён в такой же кодировке которая используется в других местах?

Comment: @Angelina_Jo как определить или сохранить в ютф8?)

Comment: В редакторе (да даже в блокноте есть выбор кодировки при сохранении файла). :-) Кстати, вы в чём кодите?